# Error al deserializar JSON en .NET C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialización

alguien sabe que trata de decir el error que marca?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Puedes incluir en tu j pregunta el código en modo texto y no como imagen? Gracias

Comment: Estoy en la red de mi trabajo y no tengo idea de qué error es, ya que no puedo ver imágenes de imgur. Por favor [evita usar imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873/).

Comment: Samano Cedillo, Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El JSON que estás intentando parsear tiene un detalle: el primer caracter es una llave **`{`** en lugar de un corchete `[`, por lo tanto vas a interpretar un *objeto* en lugar de un *arreglo*. La manera correcta de interpretarlo sería así:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);              // Interpreta el JSON en un objeto sin clase
var jToken = jObject.GetValue("objecto");       // Obtienes el valor de "objecto"
Objecto obj = jToken.ToObject(typeof(Objecto)); // Lo parsea a una instancia de tu clase
List<Answer> answers = obj.answer;              // Accedes a la lista de "Answer"
```

*Basado en [esta respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19439146/5360283).*

Answer (score 2):

El json comienza con una propiedad llamada `"Objecto"` pero estas intentado deserializar un json de tipo `List<Objecto>` y obviamente este tipo no tiene una propiedad llamada asi.

Crea una clase que contenga una propiedad de tipo `Lista<Objecto>`:

```
public class MiJson{
  public List<Objeto> objeto { get; set;}
}
```

Entonces reemplazarias :

```
var answers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Objeto>>(json);
```

Por:

```
  var answers = JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<MiJson>(json).objeto;
```